# Reflection GetMethod. select a more specific method

Tags: c#, reflection

i want to get the method but there are more then one overload. For example in object i tried to get 'Equals'. When using

```
    public virtual bool Equals(object obj);
    public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB);
```

writing `typeof(Object).GetMethod("Equals")` got me an exception, writing `typeof(Object).GetMethod("public virtual bool Equals(object obj)")` got me null. How do i specify which method i want in this case?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [one of the overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) that lets you specify the parameter types.

For example:

```
var staticMethod = typeof(Object).GetMethod("Equals",
      BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
      null,
      new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) },
      null);

var instanceMethod = typeof(Object).GetMethod("Equals",
      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
      null,
      new Type[] { typeof(object) },
      null);
```

Or alternatively:

```
var staticMethod = typeof(Object).GetMethod("Equals",
      new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) });

var instanceMethod = typeof(Object).GetMethod("Equals",
      new Type[] { typeof(object) });
```

Comment: Ah ha! i tried the overload and only used BindingFlags.Instance. No wonder why i got null (and i tried BindingFlags.Public by itself as well without thinking). I want to check if one object overrides a method so i am trying to compare these methods and i get false. Is there a way for me to see if "Equals" is the same as its base or has been overridden? -edit- i am trying to write a poor but suitable compare by reflection

Comment: @acidzombie24: I'm not sure, to be honest. I think you could probably get the method declared in this class, and then the method declared on the base class, and see whether they're the same... but I'm not sure.

Comment: I dont seem able to compare them HOWEVER i can write .GetBaseDefinition() so what i did was call this with the method in the base and that should tell me if one was overridden or not

Comment: @acidzombie24: That sounds like a good way of checking, yes :)

Comment: ahh, it didnt work. Its strange. I also looked at attributes with no luck. However i found using .DeclaringType.Name will report the classname which dummy defines as object and myclass returns itself. It looks like i am set

Answer (score 7):

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code..

---

public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

```
var ctlr = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
if (ctlr == null) return;
var invoker = ctlr.ActionInvoker as ControllerActionInvoker;
if (invoker == null) return;

var invokerType = invoker.GetType();
var getCtlrDescMethod = invokerType.GetMethod("GetControllerDescriptor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var ctlrDesc = getCtlrDescMethod.Invoke(invoker, new object[] {ctlr.ControllerContext}) as ControllerDescriptor;

var findActionMethod = invokerType.GetMethod("FindAction", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var actionDesc = findActionMethod.Invoke(invoker, new object[] { ctlr.ControllerContext, ctlrDesc, actionName }) as ReflectedActionDescriptor;
if (actionDesc == null) return;

if (actionDesc.MethodInfo.ReturnType == typeof (ActionResult))
{
    // you're in
}
```

}